# Setting brush transfer in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I want to set the brush to transfer, I tried more than 100 times but nothing. This image shows what I want:

[image]

Is it because I don't have a tablet that this function doesn't want to work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's because you do not have a tablet.

Without a tablet you can only control the fade on one end of a brush stroke. You **must** have a tablet to fade both ends.

Comment: I think the preview might be a bit misleading. The option is pen pressure, so it doesn't necessarily mean that you will always get a perfect fade at each end. Depending on what needs to be done, `pentool > stroke path and simulate pressure` might do the job: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRlyZwwtlCI